# Progress in bytes when reading CSV from URL with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tqdm

Because some of the CSV files that I need to read are very large (multiple GB), I am trying to implement a progress bar that indicates the number of bytes read out of the total when reading a CSV file from a URL with pandas.

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
from sodapy import Socrata
import contextlib
import urllib
import pandas as pd

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/PPBOpenDataDownloads/UseOfForce-All.csv?:showVizHome=no"

response = requests.get(url, params=None, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()
total_size = int(response.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))

block_size = 1000
df = []
last_position = 0
cur_position = 1
with tqdm(desc=url, total=total_size,
     unit='iB',
     unit_scale=True,
     unit_divisor=1024
     ) as bar:
    with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url=url)) as rd:
        # Create TextFileReader
        reader = pd.read_csv(rd, chunksize=block_size)
        for chunk in reader:
            df.append(chunk)
            # Here I would like to calculate the current file position: cur_position 
            bar.update(cur_position - last_position)
            last_position = cur_position
```

Is there a way to get the file position from the pandas TextFileReader somehow? Perhaps something equivalent to ftell in C++ for TextFileReader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not thoroughly tested, but you can implement custom class with `read()` method where you read from `requests` response line by line and update the `tqdm` bar:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/PPBOpenDataDownloads/UseOfForce-All.csv?:showVizHome=no"


class TqdmReader:
    def __init__(self, resp):
        total_size = int(resp.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))

        self.resp = resp
        self.bar = tqdm(
            desc=resp.url,
            total=total_size,
            unit="iB",
            unit_scale=True,
            unit_divisor=1024,
        )

        self.reader = self.read_from_stream()

    def read_from_stream(self):
        for line in self.resp.iter_lines():
            line += b"\n"
            self.bar.update(len(line))
            yield line

    def read(self, n=0):
        try:
            return next(self.reader)
        except StopIteration:
            return ""


with requests.get(url, params=None, stream=True) as resp:
    df = pd.read_csv(TqdmReader(resp))

print(len(df))
```

Prints:

```
https://public.tableau.com/views/PPBOpenDataDownloads/UseOfForce-All.csv?:showVizHome=no: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2.09M/2.09M [00:00<00:00, 2.64MiB/s]
7975
```

Comment: I have to say I like among others the trick with computing `total_size`. Both thumbs up!

Comment: This solution works with no increase in runtime when compared to reading the whole CSV at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example for doing Pandas chunked CSV reader and displaying some progress information in the case the total length or record number is missing.

- It's not always possible to know the size or total rows contained in CSV, or other Pandas reader formats ahead of time
- In this example, there is a simple chunk filtering loop that extracts some rows of the larger dataset to create a smaller dataset that fits into RAM
- The dataset in the example is [StackOverflow dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)
- We use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) with Jupyter notebook support to display HTML progress bar, which looks cleaner than text mode progress bar in notebooks
- Because when we operate on chunks, we do not know the real end of the file, we do not know how long the total operation will last - this can be changed by giving `tqdm(total=)` parameter and you get automatic estimates, but the total number must be obtained outside Pandas reader
- Regardless of whether we know total, we can always display status information like passed time and how many rows have been processed

[image: Example screenshot]

```py
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from pandas.io.parsers.readers import TextFileReader

chunk_size = 2**16  # 64k rows at a time
result_df: pd.DataFrame = None
matched_chunks: list[pd.DataFrame] = []
match_count = row_count = 0

with tqdm() as progress_bar:

    reader: TextFileReader

    rows_read = 0

    with pd.read_csv("csv/Posts.csv", chunksize=chunk_size) as reader:
        chunk: pd.DataFrame
        for chunk in reader:
            
            # Make Tags column regex friendly
            chunk["Tags"] = chunk["Tags"].fillna("")
            
            # Find posts in this chunk that match our tag filter
            matched_chunk = chunk.loc[chunk["Tags"].str.contains(tags_regex, case=False, regex=True)]
            
            matched_chunks.append(matched_chunk)

            match_count += len(matched_chunk)
            row_count += len(chunk)

            last = chunk.iloc[-1]

            # Show the date where the filter progres is going.
            # We are finished when reaching 2023-06
            progress_bar.set_postfix({
                "Date": last["CreationDate"],      
                "Matches": match_count,      
                "Total rows": f"{row_count:,}",
            })

            # Display rows read as a progress bar,
            # but we do not know the end
            progress_bar.update(len(chunk))


result_df = pd.concat(matched_chunks)
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/blockchain-stackoverflow/blob/master/create-reduced-dataset.ipynb)